# Improving the Edit Distance Algorithm

Tags: optimization, algorithms, recursive-algorithms

I applied an [Edit Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) Algorithm for similarity between two strings over the lowercase latin alphabet, where the first string has length $m$ and the second length $n$.

However I want to improve it so that i get $O(n\log(n))$ solution or something less than $O(mn)$. My string length can be $100000$.

Any suggestion or method ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int minm(int x,int y,int z){
int t= x<y?x:y;
 return t<z?t:z;


 }

int edit(int x,int y,int b,char s1[],char s2[]){

    if(s1[x]==s2[y])
        return 0;
    else
        return b;


}

int main(){

   int t,i,j,m,n,b,k,a;
   char s1[100000],s2[100000];
   scanf("%d",&t);
   while(t--){
         scanf("%s%s",s1,s2);
         scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&b,&k);
          m=strlen(s1);
          n=strlen(s2);
          int ar[m+1][n+1];
          for ( i = 0; i <=n; ++i)
          {
            /* code */
            ar[0][i]=i;
          }

          for ( i = 0; i <=m; ++i)
          {

            ar[i][0]=i;
          }


         for ( i = 1; i <=m ; ++i)
         {
            for ( j = 1; j <=n; ++j)
            {
                ar[i][j]=minm(ar[i][j-1]+a,ar[i-1][j]+a,ar[i-1][j-1]+edit(i-1,j-1,b,s1,s2));
            }

         }

       if(ar[m][n]<=k)
          printf("%d\n",ar[m][n]);
         else
            printf("-1\n");



   }






return 0;
}
```

Cost of Addition and Removal of letters is $a$ and cost of replacement is $b$.
Optimal cost is $K$. Construed as a decision problem, if least cost is greater than $K$, I print -1 (i.e cost $K$ or less is infeasible).

Here my 2d array is quite expensive for string length of $100000$. $O(mn)$ is pathetic for $n=m\ge 100000$. So I need to optimise it so that I could reduce nested loops in some order of $\le 10^6$.

Comment: alphabets are all small latin letters. Output should be the minimum cost to convert first string(s1) to second string (s2).

Comment: they are lengths of first and second strings respectively.

Comment: The information you gave in Comments needs to appear in the Question, so I undertook to make the necessary edits.  Please review to make sure I have properly stated your information.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Yeah thats exactly what i need.

Comment: The use of code to illustrate your present status is not as helpful as a detailed algorithm statement would be.  I'm guessing from the reference to 2D array that this implements a dynamic programming approach.  If you are already committed to your working code, and wish to consider only incremental changes to improve its operation, then this would be off-topic for Math.SE (we deal with mathematical problems, not so much with programming/coding problems).  If you want a discussion of the complexity of computing the Edit Distance, then that would be on-topic here.

Comment: yeah i am using dp here. Yeah i want to improve complexity only. i dont want code or anything.

Comment: To improve space complexity. I just thought of a method. Lets have two 1d array and one 2*2 matrix. Now we will use this 2*2 matrix to manipulate values from other three grids because if you look at the algorithm at every step we use only three neighbour grids which lies above and left side of the cureent grid.

Comment: hence i can definetly reduce a 10^10 space to max of 10^5 and 10^5 looks quite feasible.

Comment: The Wikipedia article [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) outlines a way to reduce the space complexity from 2D array to a pair of 1D arrays, with some loss of information retained.

Comment: This older StackOverflow Question, [Levenshtein Distance Algorithm better than O(n*m)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057513/levenshtein-distance-algorithm-better-than-onm), has references that you will find useful.  You should probably explain if an exact distance only is sought, or if approximations to the distance would be of interest.

Comment: A good summary of references is given at CS.SE, [Efficiently calculating minimum edit distance of a smaller string at each position in a larger one](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2519/efficiently-calculating-minimum-edit-distance-of-a-smaller-string-at-each-positi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, even for the standard Levenshtein distance (where $a = b = 1$), there is no known algorithm to do this faster than $O(nm)$. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057513/levenshtein-distance-algorithm-better-than-onm).

Thus, instead of trying to optimize it better than $O(nm)$, I would optimize it based on the value of $K$. I am pretty sure $K$ must be very small in your case.

Comment: yes K<=100. Even i thought of optimising it with K.Did something strike you to optimise it using K. I dont know i am not able to figure it out exactly.

Comment: In that case, the algorithm can be made to work in $O(NK)$ -- in the Dynamic Programming state, you only need to consider the states $(i, j)$ where $|i - j| \le K$ (or something like that).

Comment: yeah..! till calculated cost is less than equal to K. Like in second loop (j-i+1)*max(2*a,b) <=k Correct me if i am wrong. But still i need to track the last element. Just nothing my head to solve this :p

Comment: sorry till min(k,n)